# Vimscript `if` on based on highlighting file

Tags: vimscript

I a have PHP syntax highlighting file in `~/.vim/syntax/php.vim`. Thus, PHP functions are highlighted differently than my own custom functions and Wordpress functions. Therefore, VIM does have a way to determine if a function is a PHP built-in or not.

I am using [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16328217/343302) slightly modified to open PHP and Wordpress documentation from within VIM:

```
function! BrowseDoc()
    if b:current_syntax == "php"
        ! firefox "http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=<cword>"
        ! firefox "https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/<cword>"
    elseif b:current_syntax == "perl"
        ! firefox "http://perldoc.perl.org/search.html?q=<cword>"
    elseif b:current_syntax == "python"
        ! firefox "https://docs.python.org/3.5/search.html?q=<cword>"
    else
        return
    endif
endfunction
map <leader>ff :call BrowseDoc()<Return><Return>
```

**How might I use the VIM feature that determines if a function is to be highlighted as PHP or not to determine if php.net or wordpress.org documentation should be opened?**

I found the `phpFunctions` syn keyword in the syntax file, but I've been unable to figure out how to query if the word under the cursor is a member of that family or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can determine the current syntax group with this expression:

```
count(map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")'), "phpFunction")
```

which should return `1` if the word under the cursor belongs to the `phpFunction` group and `0` if it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you romainl. There is quite a lot that I learned from this post.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [romainl's terrific answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6204/989) I concocted this function to support all the PHP highlighting types:

```
function! BrowseDoc()
    if b:current_syntax == "php"

        " phpRegion
        let keywords_php = ['phpFCKeyword', 'phpKeyword', 'phpBoolean', 'phpClasses', 'phpConstants', 'phpFunctions', 'phpInclude', 'phpMagicConstants', 'phpServerVars', 'phpStatement', 'phpSuperglobals', 'phpType']
        let is_php = 0

        for kw in keywords_php
            if count(map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")'), kw)
                let is_php = 1
            endif
        endfor

        if is_php
            !firefox "http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=<cword>"
        else
            !firefox "https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/<cword>"
        endif

    elseif b:current_syntax == "perl"
        !firefox "http://perldoc.perl.org/search.html?q=<cword>"

    elseif b:current_syntax == "python"
        !firefox "https://docs.python.org/3.5/search.html?q=<cword>"

    else
        execute "!firefox -new-tab 'https://google.com/?q=" . &ft . "\\%20<cword>'"

    endif

endfunction
map <leader>f :call BrowseDoc()<Return><Return>
```

**Thank you romainl!**